# How can I ensure that a memory-mapped file keeps the memory pages accessible?

Tags: c++, c, qt, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I am using Qt to map a file to a piece of memory pages

```
QFile::map (qint64 offset, qint64 size, MemoryMapFlags flags = NoOptions)
```

Essentially, this should be a `mmap` system function call. I wonder how I can guarantee that I can access the returned memory, even if the file on disk is truncated. I seem to need this because I read from a disk file and want to gracefully handle errors

```
if (offset > m_file.size()) 
  // throw an error...
if (m_mappedFile != NULL) return m_mappedFile + offset;
```

Obviously, this contains a race condition, because the file size may change in between the check and the access to the mapping. How can this be avoided?

Comment: A file does not cease to exist while there are some opened descriptors that reference it - `open()`ed or `mmap()`ed. Even if another process issues a `remove()`, or if you `rm` it from the shell

Comment: @xtofpernaud yes you are right. But if i truncate it, that will modify the file associated with the file descriptor.

Comment: From man mmap: `SIGBUS Attempted  access to a portion of the buffer that does not correspond to the file
              (for example, beyond the end of  the  file,  including  the  case  where  another
              process has truncated the file)`. If this can occur in your code, you might have ton handle SIGBUS..

Comment: @xtofpernaud what if i create the file, open it, and afterwards make it read only for the duration of the usage? will i be able to truncate and write to it using the previously opened file descriptor? XXX: this won't work if i just read from the file. i may have no write access to it, but others may have.

Comment: If you `creat()` the file with appropriate permissions, then you you should be  safe, unless you launch other processes that can modify the file. Or perhaps the file does not belong to you ?

Comment: @xtofpernaud, handle SIGBUS is correct. Why not make it an answer?

Comment: @Ben Oh yes, you're right, thanks; but I was wondering why/when `mmap()`ing a file others can `truncate()` at any time, potentially loosing data..

Comment: @xtofpernaud, mandatory locking is required to make this happen, and it is not well supported on linux.

Comment: If your file is modified while opened, without synchronization with your code, you probably have more synchronization issues like this one? Like half-written changes, etc.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld i just want to be as stable as possible in the event that the file suddenly changes externally (user removing or truncating it). I am aware that there is no 100% safety.

Answer (score 3):

From `man mmap`:

```
SIGBUS Attempted  access to a portion of the buffer that does not correspond to the file
       (for example, beyond the end of  the  file,  including  the  case  where  another
       process has truncated the file).
```

So you have to install a signal handler for SIGBUS (default is to crash program)